# How do I make shell scripts work on both Linux and OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, shell, compatibility

I have a snippet of code to compile a tex document.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename="thesis"

pdflatex -shell-escape $filename
makeglossaries $filename
bibtex $filename
pdflatex $filename
pdflatex $filename

# for Ubuntu
#xdg-open $filename.pdf

# for mac
open $filename.pdf
```

How do I make this script work on both Linux and OS X? I think it should be something like,

```
if is Linux; then
    xdg-open $filename.pdf
elif is OS X; then
    open $filename.pdf
fi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard way to detect the current platform is to call [`uname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uname):

```
uname=$(uname);
case "$uname" in
    (*Linux*) openCmd='xdg-open'; ;;
    (*Darwin*) openCmd='open'; ;;
    (*CYGWIN*) openCmd='cygstart'; ;;
    (*) echo 'error: unsupported platform.'; exit 2; ;;
esac;
"$openCmd" "$filename.pdf";
```

Comment: You're welcome. In all cases you could remove the first of the three semicolons if you wanted to, and you could also remove the final double-semicolon (the one in the last case branch). I just like to be explicit about statement termination; I like to include the single semicolon terminator for all bash statements, regardless where they occur, and I like to include the double-semicolon on all case branches. One of the benefits is that it allows you to join multiple statements onto a single line and never have to worry about adding semicolons. Another benefit is consistency.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to detect the OS, I would suggest that you try do *feature detection*, i.e. before using something that is not implemented in all platforms, try to detect it that thing is supported by the *current platform*, whatever that is. You could do something like that as follows

```
if command -v xdg-open >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    xdg-open $filename.pdf
elif command -v open >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    open $filename.pdf
else
    echo >&2 "I don't know how to open the pdf"
fi
```

The `command -v xdg-open >/dev/null 2>&1` above will check if a program called `xdg-open` is available in your path. If it is, we'll use just that. Otherwise, we will try a different option.

Comment: This is smart, +1. However it should be mentioned that this is not 100% foolproof. It's possible for a command with the same name to exist on a different platform, even though it's not the intended command. For `command -v`, even the existence of an alias or shell function with the same name could trip up the code.

Comment: Good points. I wouldn't worry for `xdg-open`, but `open` is too generic indeed.